# looking to implement a search feature into my website from Swifttype.com where someone on the site can easily search for anything thats available

Tags: javascript, html, search, web, search-engine

Basically, I went to the website https://app.swiftype.com/home and made an account for this search feature which helps search for things better on my website. After creating the account I have multiple ways of transferring my website information I chose by submitting my URL - https://villagemortgage.mymortgage-online.com/index.html - Immediately after transferring my URL I was able to preview on their website samples of how it will work. Finally, they generated some code that needs to be copy and pated into every page of my site, but I am assuming that's not enough. So my question is What type of HTML do I need for this search to actually work

Here is the code Swifttype generated to copy....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function(w,d,t,u,n,s,e){w['SwiftypeObject']=n;w[n]=w[n]||function(){
  (w[n].q=w[n].q||[]).push(arguments);};s=d.createElement(t);
  e=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];s.async=1;s.src=u;e.parentNode.insertBefore(s,e);
  })(window,document,'script','//s.swiftypecdn.com/install/v2/st.js','_st');

  _st('install','UY3ZeyyV1a9gMxxgfq-L','2.0.0');
</script>
```

Is this code enough to link it to a simple search box created from HTML?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the default search input field

```html
<input type="text" class="st-default-search-input">
```

And this will allow your search to work.

Comment: okay I see now what it does but how do I link it to the code they provided to actually make it search for the items from my website

Comment: It should automatically link as long as the swifttype API is included in your website header.